# How many cards per booster pack in the Core M12 Sealed Booster Box?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-drafting

I want to buy a booster box to hold some office drafts.

I remember booster packs as having 15 cards per pack, which is in line with what [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booster_pack):

> Starting with the Shards of Alara block, booster packs for both Core Sets and Expansions began to contain 1 land, 10 commons, 3 uncommons, either 1 rare (7/8 chance) or 1 mythic rare (1/8 chance)

But the [Amazon page for the Core M12 Sealed Booster Box](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004VJBODI) says that there are "10 Cards/Pack".

Did something change, or is the Amazon page wrong?

Answer (score 9):

It's probably an error, as M12 only had 15 card booster packs (as can be seen in any online store catalog like [this one](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/?mainPage=showSearchResult&searchFor=2012)). As far as I could find, the last core set to have smaller boosters was M11 with [6-card packs](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Magic_2011_Six_card_Booster.c2p253815.prod).

Comment: Indeed. All M12 boosters contain 15 cards.

Comment: I have seen the 6 card boosters in big-box stores for M13. But yes, I've never seen nor heard of a 10 card booster pack for any recent set (or actually, any set).

Comment: @corsiKa I answered this before m13 came out :p Still haven't found a single m12 booster pack with less than 15 cards.